# Embedding tcl in ruby

Tags: ruby, tcl

Is there any way to do this? It seems the only possible way to do this is by using ruby/tk and creating a tcl interpreter through that api. However, I'd like to use this on a system with no GUI (x windows). Am I out of options?

Thanks

Comment: Python's Tkinter allows the user to create an instance of the Tcl interpreter that does not load Tk (parameter `useTk` for `Tk`'s constructor). Maybe Ruby's wrapper does too ?

Comment: Why do you need to embed it and just not shell out? Did you look at http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/tcl-for-rubyists.html ?

Answer (score 3):

If you can invoke arbitrary simple functions in Tcl's C API, the key ones are:

- `Tcl_FindExecutable` – Call this first to initialize the library
- `Tcl_CreateInterp` – This returns a handle for a new execution context
- `Tcl_Eval` – This evaluates a script; returns constants `TCL_OK` (0) or `TCL_ERROR` (1) (or a few others which are rare in general code)
- `Tcl_GetResult` – This returns the result value (or error message)
- `Tcl_ResetResult` – This clears the result value
- `Tcl_DeleteInterp` – Maybe you can guess what this does…

You can also access "global" variables in the context with `Tcl_GetVar` and `Tcl_SetVar`; this is a very convenient way to pass in values that might not be valid scripts.

Comment: Is there any way to specify the path to the tcl interpreter?

Comment: With `mkmf.rb`, you'll need `have_library` or `find_library`. I'm not nearly a good enough Ruby programmer to tell you how to make good use of that API.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on the command line you can shell out to tclsh. tcl also has a C api so you should be able to use this to embed tcl in ruby if there is no preexisting way?

Answer (score 0):

> Q. Embedding tcl in ruby[.] Is there any way to do this?

I came across
[this post](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/run-tcl-in-ruby.818976/#post-4454838)
by
[Matz](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=887170269&title=Yukihiro_Matsumoto)
himself in 2005, from a thread called, "Run TCL in ruby".

His example program (from the post) evaluates strings of Tcl code from Ruby without shelling out:

```rb
require 'tcltklib'

def test
  ip1 = TclTkIp.new

  puts ip1._eval('button .lab -text exit -command "destroy ."').inspect
  puts ip1._eval('pack .lab').inspect

  puts ip1._eval(%q+puts [ruby {print "print by ruby\n"; 'puts by tcl/tk'}]+).inspect

  TclTkLib.mainloop
end

test
```

Its console output is:

```
".lab"
""
print by ruby
puts by tcl/tk
""
```

Quoting from his post:

> The tcltklib extension, which comes with the standard distribution, invokes Tcl interpreter directly without any inter-process communication.

To make it work, I needed to duplicate the following directories:

1. `/c/Ruby/lib/tcltk/tcl8.5` as `/c/Ruby/lib/tcl8.5`
2. `/c/Ruby/lib/tcltk/tk8.5` as `/c/Ruby/lib/tk8.5`

(Possibly, your Ruby is installed somewhere else.)

> Q. I'd like to use this on a system with no GUI (x windows).

In a reply post immediately below Matz's, Hidetoshi Nagai says:

> If no need for Tk, an IP without Tk can be created. To do that, please call `TclTkIp.new(nil, false)`.

So here is Matz's program, altered to run without a Tk graphics window:

```rb
require 'tcltklib'

def test
# nil, false means without Tk:
  ip1 = TclTkIp.new nil, false

  puts ip1._eval('list { aa bb cc }').inspect

  puts ip1._eval('set list { aa bb cc }; join $list ""').inspect

  TclTkLib.mainloop
end

test
```

Its console output is:

```
"{ aa bb cc }"
"aabbcc"
```

These two programs worked for me, using Ruby 2.2.5 (with Tk 8.5.12) on Windows 7.

For what it's worth, here is the
[manual](http://github.com/ruby/tk/blob/master/MANUAL_tcltklib.eng)
for `tcltklib`.