# Invoking Tcl proc in multithreaded mode

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcl

My function `func()` is being called by multiple threads. (Each thread will call this function only once.)

From inside the `func()`, I want each thread to call a Tcl proc named `tcl_proc_name` (which takes no arguments).

For this, I did like this

> Tcl_Eval( Tcl_CreateInterp() , "tcl_proc_name");

But it somehow this code is not able to invoke the Tcl proc.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The way you embed and initialise a Tcl environment is incomplete. Have you searched SO for relevant answers? See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230757/using-the-tcl-interpreter-repeatedly-inside-a-c-program/55230961#55230961 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645671/embedding-tcl-in-ruby/2645938#2645938. Also, check out the [Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+to+embed+Tcl+in+C+applications) for recipes of embedding Tcl in your C or C++ application.

Comment: I found out that my main interpreter knows of some commands that were registered with that interpreter. But when i create the thread specific interpreter, it did not know about any of those comamnds .. is there a way to inherit all the commands of the main interpreter to the thread specific interpreter ? – Deepika Bansal 21 mins ago    Delete

Answer (score 0):

Every Tcl interpreter (i.e., every instance of `Tcl_Interp`) is strongly bound *by design* to the thread that creates it; the implementation internally uses thread-specific data extensively so as to virtually completely avoid the need for major locks (like the Global Interpreter Lock that bedevils performant multithreaded Python code). Tcl commands are utterly bound to the interpreter that contains them. You have to either:

1. Send messages to a single thread to perform the action. (See the `Tcl_QueueEvent()` function, or use the Thread package's `thread::send` command from the Tcl level.)
2. Duplicate the command in multiple interpreters, one per thread. That might be easy or complex in your application.

For avoidance of all doubt: you ***cannot*** safely use a Tcl interpreter from multiple threads. It *will not work; guaranteed.* It will cause crashes.

Comment: I found out that my main interpreter knows of some commands that were registered with that interpreter. But when i create the thread specific interpreter, it did not know about any of those comamnds .. is there a way to inherit all the commands of the main interpreter to the thread specific interpreter ? – Deepika Bansal 21 mins ago    Delete